# Query with multiple fields of a derived table

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, postgis, derived-table

I have the following tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "walks"
(
    id    varchar(36),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "points"
(
    id          varchar(36),
    time        timestamp(6) with time zone,
    geometry    geometry(Point, 4326),
    walk_id     varchar(36),
    FOREIGN KEY (walk_id)
        REFERENCES walks (id)
)
```

You can think of a `walk` as representing an ordered set of points strung together:
`---O------O---O-O-----O---`

I'm trying to select all the points in order of a walk, but only for the walks that intersect a given Polygon (*i.e. walks that have points inside the Polygon*). Additionally, I want to select a boolean representing whether each returned point is inside that area or not.

I've come up with the following query, **which works correctly:**

```sql
SELECT p.id,
       w.id       AS walk_id,
       p.geometry,
       p.id IN (SELECT id
                FROM   points
                WHERE  ST_INTERSECTS(p.geometry,
'SRID=4326;POLYGON((-81.8 -0.5,-81.1 -0.5,-81.1 -1.5,-81.8 -1.5,-81.8 -0.5))'
        )) AS in_area
FROM   points p
       JOIN walks w
         ON w.id = p.walk_id
WHERE  w.id IN (SELECT w.id
                FROM   walks w
                       JOIN points p
                         ON p.walk_id = w.id
                WHERE  ST_INTERSECTS(p.geometry,
'SRID=4326;POLYGON((-81.8 -0.5,-81.1 -0.5,-81.1 -1.5,-81.8 -1.5,-81.8 -0.5))'
))
ORDER  BY p.time ASC;
```

This seems inefficient though, since the PostGIS Intersects function has to be called twice on everything.

Is it possible to select both the intersecting point IDs and walk IDs in a derived table or something, and then reference them both in the SELECT (for the boolean) and the WHERE (to filter the correct walks)?

Comment: Hi! Could you provide some sample data and the expected result? cheers

Answer (score 2):

Without sample data it is quite hard to fully understand your use case, but maybe a CTE would simplify things a bit. Something like:

```
WITH p AS (
  SELECT id,geometry,walk_id,time,
   ST_Intersects(geometry,
    'SRID=4326;POLYGON((-81.8 -0.5,-81.1 -0.5,-81.1 -1.5,-81.8 -1.5,-81.8 -0.5))') AS in_area   
  FROM points )
SELECT p.id,w.id AS walk_id,p.geometry,p.in_area FROM p
JOIN walks w ON w.id = p.walk_id
WHERE p.in_area IS TRUE ORDER BY p.time ASC;
```